# Where should i post question

Tags: discussion

I am very new to this site.Please can any one tell me where can i post my questions.I am trying using "Ask Question " link but it does not post my question and just gives suggested questions.

Comment: You just asked a question. It seems to have worked. What is the issue?

Comment: I think there is a button on the bottom of that page you need to click. I'm searching for the question that showed exactly what to do, but I've had no luck yet.

Answer (score 2):

> just gives suggested questions.

That is a default setting. When you type the subject of the question it lists all the question which matches your question so that if your question has been already been answered then you can save all the trouble of asking a duplicate question.

See this screenshot

[image]

I would recommend visiting those suggestions if you see a match. And still if you do not find what you are looking for then ignore those suggestions and give a unique subject to your question, describe your question and then click on `Post Your Question` like you did for this question. :)

Comment: The screen for new users in SO is different than that.

Comment: @RalZarek: It could be but it still gives the same suggestions when you ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

This is the site users with less than 10 rep are seeing when trying to ask a new question:[image]
Check the Checkbox then click "proceed".

Comment: Now i got it.Thanks every one.